# How to update sibling checkboxes in React on Checkbox change?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have the following React code that updates checkboxes in a shopping cart, based on what items are places in the cart:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "./circlecheckbox.css";
import { Checkbox } from "aws-amplify-react";
import { addToCart, removeFromCart } from "actions";
import { ICartState } from "reducer/cartReducer";

interface IState {
  cart: ICartState;
}

interface IProps {
  removeFromCart: Function;
  addToCart: Function;
  id: number;
  cart: any[];
}

const CircleCheckbox: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  addToCart,
  removeFromCart,
  id,
  cart,
}) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(cart.some((prod) => prod.id === id));

  return (
    <Checkbox
      onChange={(e: any) => {
        setChecked(!checked);
        if (e.target.checked === true) {
          addToCart(id);
        } else if (e.target.checked === false) {
          removeFromCart(id);
        }
      }}
      checked={checked}
    />
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: IState) => {
  return {
    cart: state.cart.cart,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addToCart, removeFromCart })(
  CircleCheckbox
);
```

Here is an image showing how the cart looks like:

[image: initial shopping cart]

As you can see, the same product (with different times) is placed in the cart several times. I don't want this to happen, and want to uncheck a previous Checkbox, if the same product is bought twice. Since I changed the Redux store to update correctly, when I refresh the page I get the desired result (see image below)

[image: Image after refresh]

How can I get the same effect as refreshing the page, whenever a Checkbox is toggled? How can I update a sibling Checkbox when another sibling is toggled?

Here is the Redux Reducer-code that updates the component:

```
import { ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_FROM_CART, UPDATE_CURRENCY } from "actions/types";
import { products } from "assets/products";
import Logger from "service/logging/Logger";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  products,
  currency: "NOK",
  cart: [],
};

export type ICartState = typeof INITIAL_STATE;
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      let addedItem = state.products.find((item) => item.id === action.id);
      Logger("cart", addedItem?.name + " was added to cart");
      const existsInCart = state.cart.some(
        (prod: any) => prod.id === action.id
      );

      if (existsInCart) {
        return state;
      }

      const sameNameInCart = state.cart.some(
        (prod: any) => prod.name === addedItem?.name
      );

      if (sameNameInCart) {
        let items_to_keep = state.cart.filter(
          (prod: any) => prod.name !== addedItem?.name
        );

        return {
          ...state,
          cart: [...items_to_keep, addedItem],
        };
      }

      if (addedItem && addedItem.details !== "Free") {
        return {
          ...state,
          months: addedItem.period,
          cart: [...state.cart, addedItem],
        };
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        cart: [...state.cart, addedItem],
      };

    case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
      let new_items = state.cart.filter((item: any) => item.id !== action.id);

      if (action.id === "DBmasker") {
        return {
          ...state,
          months: 0,
          cart: new_items,
        };
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: new_items,
      };
    case UPDATE_CURRENCY:
      return {
        ...state,
        currency: action.currency,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Have question. Why dont you filter your duplicate product element? In that way only unique element will be remained

Comment: That is what I am doing in the Redux store in the background :) so the state is correct, I just want to update the other Checkboxes every time one of them is clicked. So that I get the same effect as refreshing the page

Comment: Can you share your redux code or share barebone of your code on codesandbox?

Comment: I added the reducer code where all the logic happens :) the actions are dispatched properly

Comment: Its not helpful basically want to understand suppose if you have same product . How do you save that data? Do you track which one is clicked which one not?